# How to make the appendix follow the same style as the template?

Tags: texshop

I am making final tweaks in my thesis. I have a template from a previous student that I am using to abide by the university's thesis formatting guidelines. I had put the appendices before the references, and the appendix style was the same as the rest of the document (font size and line spacing in particular).

However, I have to put the appendices after the references (university requirement). Doing so modifies the style of the appendices, which now differs from the rest of the document.

I created a minimal working example.

thesis.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,thesis]{OUdissertation4} %Use 'thesis' for MS and 
'dissertation' for Ph.D. dissertation style

\usepackage{enumitem} %for item lists
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib} %bibliography
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix} %for appendix

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\title{thesis title}
\author{author}

\begin{preface} 
\prefacesection{Acknowledgments}
\par
Here are the acknowledgements. blablabla blabla blablabla blablablablabla         blablablablabla blablablablabla blabla

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\prefacesection{Abstract}
\par
Here is the abstract. blablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla     blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blabla

\end{preface}

\chapter{Introduction}
Here is one chapter. I am citing \cite{ieee}. blablabla blablablablabla     blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla     blabla

\newpage  
\references{ieeetr}{references}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{ATD}
\label{app_ATD}
Since the first measurement campaign focuses on the ATD antenna, the case     studies for the WSR-88D, RaXPol, and the 5G base station antennas will be repeated     for the ATD specifically. The ATD has the following characteristics:
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item It comprises 76 panels for a total of 4864 elements.
\item It has an area of 12.6 m\textsuperscript{2} and a maximum dimension of 4.06 m.
\item It has a gain of 42.3 dBi, beamwidths of 1.7$^\circ$ in azimuth and     1.6$^\circ$ in elevation, a peak power of 58.4 kW, and operates at 3.1 GHz.
\end{itemize}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```
@ARTICLE{ieee, 
author={}, 
journal={ANSI/IEEE Std 149-1979}, 
title="{IEEE Standard Test Procedures for Antennas}", 
year={1979}, 
volume={}, 
number={}, 
pages={s}, 
doi={10.1109/IEEESTD.1979.120310}, 
ISSN={}, 
month={},
}
```

The template file is very long, I put it on Drive: [template file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YzB5idXmJ1N_7iw_LOXdQ0mRmtuj9Wiz)

> **Update Manuel Kuehner** I put it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/TgL5guJB. According to the content, the class file was last revised March 3, 2004.

Any idea how I can have those appendices follow the style from the template ? It might be something really easy, but my latex skills are limited.

Thanks!